# Are the following two big-list questions posted by me welcome here?

Tags: discussion

Are the following two big-list questions posted by me welcome here?

[Was sind gute Zungenbrecher im Deutschen? / What are good German tongue-twisters?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/95/was-sind-gute-zungenbrecher-im-deutschen-what-are-good-german-tongue-twisters)

[German words with interesting etymology](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/97/german-words-with-interesting-etymology/98#98)

I think that these are question that could have a edifying collection of answers, but that they are close to the borderline, so I wanted to put them up for discussion.

I propose that you upvote my question here if you welcome the questions, downvote my question here if you think that they do not belong, and write an answer if you have a more nuanced response.

Comment: Especially the question on etymology is too subjective.

Comment: I was thinking about asking a list question along the lines of "What german language movies are good for learners trying be build vocab/improve grammar?"  I think this could be too similarly broad, although might work as a community wiki.

Comment: You should have made this a community wiki before instructing people to use it as a poll. :-)

Answer (score 7):

I find both questions very interesting and would personally like to see them open, but I fear they're both "list of X" questions that have proven counterproductive on other, older SE network sites. The Zungenbrecher one less so than the etymology one.

It's on those grounds that I tend to vote against having them.

Answer (score 1):

I voted to close the question on interesting etymology, because the topic is highly subjective.
Personally, I found the answer about the Neanderthaler very interesting, but the other not.

As Pekka already stated, such questions to accumulate wisdom have been counterproductive on other SE sites.
Moreover, most people will not look at all the pages of the question if too much answers exists, thus rendering the voting mechanism less useful.
Therefore, I am against such "big list" questions.